# Invalid Plugin Configuration: testErrorIgnore

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cucumber, pom.xml

I'm getting the following error in my POM file:

POM file:
[image: POM file]

Error:
[image: error message]

I tried to transfer my cucumber project to another machine, but the only warning to pop up was `Invalid Plugin configuration :Test Error Ignore`.

I've researched this issue but cannot find anything related.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer it was visible all this time:

instead of

```
<suiteXmlFiles>
<!-- <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile> -->
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <testErrorIgnore>false</testErrorIgnore>
                        <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
```

it should have been:

```
<!-- <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile> -->
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <testErrorIgnore>false</testErrorIgnore>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                '</suiteXmlFiles>'
```

My oversight.